# Using BreezeJS with Entity-Framework mapped procedures

Tags: entity-framework, angularjs, breeze, hottowel

I have an application based on the John Papa HotTowel-Angular-Breeze Template with an EF model.  in my case I have several entities that have Insert, Update, Delete Procedures mapped to the Entities in question.  When I update an object in the Client it is persisting the data, but not using the mapped stored procedures.  has anyone else seen this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

With EF6, you can use CodeFirst Fluent API to map your entities to the stored procedures like so in your DbContext.

```
modelBuilder
  .Entity<YourEntity>()
  .MapToStoredProcedures();
```

By default, EF will expect your stored procs to be named as YourEntity_insert, YourEntity_update and YourEntity_delete.

If you want to override the default names, you can do so using,

```
modelBuilder 
  .Entity<YourEntity>() 
  .MapToStoredProcedures(s => 
    s.Update(u => u.HasName("update_YourEntity")));
```

The [EF CodePlex](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=code%20first%20insert/update/delete%20stored%20procedure%20mapping) has some more documentation on this.

I did a quick proof of concept with my HotTowel-Angular-Breeze app and it seems to work.

Hope this helps.